# Custom Bootstrap Vertical Layout

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to build a vertical row layout using Bootstrap, only problem is that when I adjust the height it pushes the other column down the page and out of place. I have drawn up a quick example of what I'm trying to do. Is this possible using Bootstrap or would a custom CSS have to be written? [layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MnPA.png)

Comment: You can use bootstrap... buti suggest to use [bootstrap 5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/getting-started/introduction/) because it is more recent. If you have some problems with your code i'll suggest also to read [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-3">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-12"> ... </div>
   <div class="col-12"> ... </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-3"> ... </div>
 <div class="col-3"> ... </div>
 <div class="col-3">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-12"> ... </div>
   <div class="col-12"> ... </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked flawlessly. Didn't think it was that easy.